# Random number generator where the 1st and 2nd derivatives of consecutive values is relatively small

Tags: random, curve, smoothing, derivative

If you were to graph a list of values returned by this algorithm, it might seem smooth and wavy. This would be good for realistic terrain generation, or maybe a unique way of making white noise.

Comment: Unclear what you're actually asking. To compute, say, 1st derivative you have to have abscissas x1 and x2 value of function at x1 and x2 (f1 and f2).Then, at least, you could make a guess about value of derivative etc. What x1, x2, f1, f2 would be in you case? How you compute it?

Comment: Note that nowhere in your topic or post have you actually asked a question yet. So: what is your question? (being mindful of [what's on topic](/help/on-topic), of course, so no "does anyone know of a library that does this" because that will just get your question closed for very obvious reasons)

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you generate uniform or normal "small signed numbers" and integrate them twice via summation, the goal will be achieved. But a theoretical justification will be much better than my shot in the dark - go ask on Math.SE.

Comment: @Maurdekye mhm, although I am currently being brainwashed how the normal distribution is the cure for cancer and solution to all world problems, so I would use a Gaussian with expectation 0 and sigma = (1/6)(max-min).